# Wicket: What to keep in mind when making a (CDI-enabled) Page Serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, wicket, cdi, serializable

What do I need to keep in mind when making a Wicket Page Serializable?

I'm especially concerned about CDI beans - is it okay to rely on seam-wicket to re-inject beans as necessary?

```
public class ChannelLogPage extends BaseLayoutPage implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChannelLogPage.class);

    @Inject private ChannelManager channelManager;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of the CDI spec to inject serializable proxy so you must be safe.
Wicket does this for its Spring and Guice integrations but for CDI there is no such need.

Comment: However I keep getting https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-3949  and I doubt it's anything mine - basically, I only have `@Inject`-ed beans and components...?

Comment: The spec requires the bean to be serializable if in session scope, but I've only found a single reference about serializable (passivation-capable) proxies, required when "a bean with normal scope is injected into a bean with a passivating scope" (pg.43@cdi.spec). Since the Wicket Page itself is not a CDI bean, I don't think proxy injection is guaranteed, at least not by the spec (implementations may do it). I don't know about the seam-wicket integration (doesn't Weld have a CDI-specific wicket integration?).

Comment: seam-wicket is de-facto Weld's wicket integration. Originally it was named weld-wicket. And it injects proxies. I'll verify with Wicket 1.4.19 since Martin fixed WICKET-3949 (Thanks pal :)